# Export Data from Tables without Carriage Return/Enter

Tags: sql-server, export-to-csv

I am trying to export data from MS SQL table, one column stores data from text area and lot of them have Carriage keys and commas in them, this is messing up the csv file. How can I export data without CR and is it possible to export it in colon separated instead of comma ?

Answer (score 0):

In general it depends on how smart is your "receiver" of CSV.

It is normal to export column containing Carriage return e.g. html code fragments stored in database.
 Solutions to export such columns are:

1. Wrap column contents in delimiters (usually quotas but you can choose your own).
2. Replace CR by special unique character sequence and then replace this sequence to CR on the other side of export.

All of this can be done using "Export Data" task in SSMS.
For method 1 you can use "Text qualifier option" option, for method 2 you should write a query to replace CR sequence.

Please look at documentation:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052%28v=sql.100%29.aspx